# Problem displaying PDF in React from UInt8Array (react-pdf)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf

I'm trying to build a PDF viewer in React, I've already built the backend to upload the files and fetch the buffer data. But I'm having some problems with react-pdf, as I can't seem to serve the right type of data.
This is the code I've written:

```
const [data, setData] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/files/pdf-test.pdf")
      .then((res) => res.text())
      .then((res) => setData(new Buffer(res, "binary")));
  });

  return (
    <>
      <Document file={{ data: data }} />
    </>
  );
```

This is one of the few tries I've made, in this one the backend serves the binary data of the file, and if we console log the last `.then` we can see that I'm serving the `Document` a UInt8Array, which is the recommended data format:

[image: Data]

Apart from the code in the image, I've also tried it with binary and an ArrayBuffer, but still no results, changing both the backend and frontend code.
The error I get is:
[image]

**TL;DR**: I'm trying to display PDF files in React with react-pdf using their buffer but I can't manage to do it. I have already made a backend to upload files (express-fileupload) and store them so that their data can be fetched.

Thank u for helping, and I'm open to other approaches to the problem

Answer (score 0):

For RCA (react-create-app) you need to config the worker in order to view your PDF file.

```
import { Document, Page, pdfjs } from 'react-pdf';
```

Then configure it like this:

```
pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = `//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/${pdfjs.version}/pdf.worker.js`;
```

Usage:

```
const [uint8Arr, setUint8Arr] = useState();

function getUint8Array() {
 let reader = new FileReader();

            // reader.readAsDataURL(selectedFile); base64
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(selectedFile);
            reader.onloadend = async (e) => {
                if ( e.target?.result instanceof ArrayBuffer) {
                    const uint8Array = new Uint8Array(e.target.result);
                    setUint8Arr(uint8Array) <---- 

                    // more callbacks(file.name, Buffer.from(new Uint8Array(target.result)));
                }
            };
}
<Document file={{
            data: uint8Arr <----
        }} onLoadSuccess={() => console.log('SUCCESS LOAD')}>
            <Page pageNumber={1} />
        </Document>
```

Hope that this will fix your issue.